# Can someone explain this solution?

Tags: ruby, math

The prime factors of `13195` are `5`, `7`, `13` and `29`.
What is the largest prime factor of the number `600851475143` ?

```
def largest_prime(number)
  i = 2
  largest_divisor = 0
  while i < number
    if number % i == 0
      largest_divisor = i
      number = number / i
      i = 2
    else
      i += 1
    end
  end
  number
end
```

Comment: You question title asks one question and your body asks us to solve a "Homework problem". What part of this code do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

The while-loop always looks for the smallest divisor of `number` (except 1).
If we find one, we store it, divide `number` and start anew.

Since we take the *smallest* divisor, this always stores a prime.

The loop can only end, if `number == 1`, which means we have divided by every factor.
And the last factor, that remained had to be the largest.

Comment: ah thats what i didnt understand why the number would become number / i  thankyou

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer, if you have enough reputation to do so. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.